# How to add anther "entry" into this JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I downloaded some JSON, as shown below. In the developer console it looks like an object containing nested objects which contain nested objects ...

I would like to add a new, empty "campaign" into the data (at the front). How do I do that?

Insert

```
var blankCampaignData = {'title': '', 'description': '', 'path_to_logo': '', 'start_time': date, 'end_time' : date, 'paused': false};
```

into

```
{
    "campaigns": {
        "1": {
            "campaign_id": "1",
            "title": "Nike Air 2015 campaign",
            "description": null,
            "path_to_logo": null,
            "start_time": "09/11/2015 22:42:08",
            "end_time": "09/03/2016 22:42:08",
            "paused": "0",
            "destinations": {
                "1": {
                    "destination_id": "1",
                    "campaign_id": "1",
                    "url": "www.nike.com/nike_air",
                    "description": "Nike air destination",
                    "connections": {
                        "3": {
                            "connection_id": "3",
                            "destination_id": "1",
                            "tag_id": "0",
                            "country": "Scotland",
                            "county": "Yorkshire",
                            "town": "East Ham",
                            "post_code": "SE1 1AA",
                            "custom": "bus stop",
                            "description": "Connection number 3"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "2": {
                    "destination_id": "2",
                    "campaign_id": "1",
                    "url": "www.nike.com/nike_air/sub_campaign",
                    "description": "Nike air - free laces promotion destination",
                    "connections": {
                        "2": {
                            "connection_id": "2",
                            "destination_id": "2",
                            "tag_id": "0",
                            "country": "Engerland",
                            "county": "Devon",
                            "town": "East Ham",
                            "post_code": "SE1 1AA",
                            "custom": "bus stop",
                            "description": "Connection number 2"
                        },
                        "4": {
                            "connection_id": "4",
                            "destination_id": "2",
                            "tag_id": "0",
                            "country": "Engerland",
                            "county": "Yorkshire",
                            "town": "Felixswtowe",
                            "post_code": "RB3 9YR",
                            "custom": "police staticon",
                            "description": "Connection number 4"
                        },
                        "6": {
                            "connection_id": "6",
                            "destination_id": "2",
                            "tag_id": "0",
                            "country": "Scotland",
                            "county": "Essex",
                            "town": "York",
                            "post_code": "JD8 4LF",
                            "custom": "somewhere else",
                            "description": "Connection number 6"
                        },
                        "9": {
                            "connection_id": "9",
                            "destination_id": "2",
                            "tag_id": "0",
                            "country": "Scotland",
                            "county": "Cork",
                            "town": "York",
                            "post_code": "JD8 4LF",
                            "custom": "in the ladies' loo",
                            "description": "Connection number 9"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "campaign_id": "2",
            "title": "Nike football boots campaign",
            "description": null,
            "path_to_logo": null,
            "start_time": "09/12/2015 22:42:08",
            "end_time": "09/01/2016 22:42:08",
            "paused": "0",
            "destinations": {
                "3": {
                    "destination_id": "3",
                    "campaign_id": "2",
                    "url": "www.nike.com/nike_football_boots/",
                    "description": "Nike footie boots destination",
                    "connections": {}
                },
                "4": {
                    "destination_id": "4",
                    "campaign_id": "2",
                    "url": "www.nike.com/nike_football_boots/sub_campaign",
                    "description": "Buy left boot, get right boot free destination",
                    "connections": {}
                }
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "campaign_id": "3",
            "title": "Nike general promotion campaign",
            "description": null,
            "path_to_logo": null,
            "start_time": "09/12/2013 22:42:08",
            "end_time": "09/08/2016 22:42:08",
            "paused": "0",
            "destinations": {
                "5": {
                    "destination_id": "5",
                    "campaign_id": "3",
                    "url": "www.nike.com/general_promotion",
                    "description": "Nike general promotion destination",
                    "connections": {}
                },
                "6": {
                    "destination_id": "6",
                    "campaign_id": "3",
                    "url": "www.nike.com/general_promotion/discount_coupon",
                    "description": "20% off coupon destination",
                    "connections": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884840/adding-a-new-array-element-to-a-json-object

Comment: Yes, but push only applies to arrays (I am extremely new to JS,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work out what the next campaign id should be:

```
var nextId = +Object.keys(obj.campaigns).sort().pop() + 1;
```

Add the empty campaign to the campaigns object. Obviously you'll need to define `date` beforehand.

```
obj.campaigns[nextId] = {
  'title': '',
  'description': '',
  'path_to_logo': '',
  'start_time': date,
  'end_time' : date,
  'paused': false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Btw, I would prefer to add it at the front

Comment: You can't. Objects aren't sorted. If `campaigns` was an array then you could [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) the new object as the first element.

Comment: To add it at the front, cold I take the new object and add the existing one to the end of that?

Comment: "In front" and "behind" make no sense because objects __are not ordered__. The only way for it to make sense would be to be to move the object with key 1 to a new key and replace it with the new object.

Comment: A good point (+1), but I will `ng-repeat` over the data and want the new one to appear first on the screen. I will either do as you sat and overwrite the first key (but that would mean shuffling every entry down, to insert at front) or append the existing object to the new, empty one.

Comment: You'll either have to adjust your PHP to give you an array of objects then, or do what I suggested and move the object with id=1 to a new object and then assign the new object to key 1. Sounds like changing the PHP would be better for you in the long run.

Comment: I wondered if I could do that. Your comments spurred me to search and I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408311/return-an-array-of-objects  `while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))`  Thanks!!  Now I only have to figure out how to get PHP to nest the tree structure (each campaign has multiple destinations, each of which have multiple connections), so I use 3 nested loops, each with a `SELECT` statement

Comment: I can't figure it out, so I posted a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196818/return-an-array-of-array-of-arrays-of-objects   Future readers of this question may want to look there (as might @Andy ;-)